# Soundcloud API - Playback_count is wrong

Tags: soundcloud

Hey SoundCloud guys the value of all playback_counts delivered by your API is wrong over 1 month now. Please fix it. We can't countinue working with this wrong stats...

Comment: Try the API V2 as a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976285/soundcloud-api-playback-count-different-than-on-website/36985629#36985629