# SoundCloud API playback_count different than on website

Tags: soundcloud

Your API returns a different play_count than you display on your website.

Example Website:

https://soundcloud.com/esbee/aleah-water-and-wine-stefan-biniak-private-edit-remastered

Playback Count: 10.2k

Example API:

[https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/260065214?client_id=removed

"playback_count":1132

That's a factor of 10.

Can you please have a look at it or am I missing something?

Comment: Duplicate of (at least): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859733/soundcloud-api-playback-count-is-wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use their v2 api:
https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/tracks/260065214?client_id=ADD_YOURS
Which lists the play count at a proper 10300+

However there doesn't seem to be any documentation about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253633/soundcloud-is-api-v2-allowed-to-be-used-and-is-there-documentation-on-it